# App crashes when accessing NSMutableArray Count ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I landed into a weird problem where i cannot use array.count that crashes my app.

```
@interface LAMasterViewController ()

NSMutableArray * claimReports

@end
    -(void)  ViewDidLoad
    {
       claimReports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [claimReports addObjectsFromArray:[[LADataModelController getSingleton] getClaimReportsOrderedByIncidentDate] ];

    }

-(NSArray *) getClaimReportsOrderedByIncidentDate
{ // it returns one record
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ClaimReport" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByIncidentDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateOfIncident" ascending:NO];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortByIncidentDate]];

    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Array Count %i" ,array.count);
    return  array;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

  return claimReports.count; //crashes here

}
```

> error:
>   -[LSClaimReport count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa54afc0
>   2014-04-01 14:56:29.022 LossAdjusting[6956:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LSClaimReport count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa54afc0'

What have i missed here. Seems a silly one. please guide.
Thanks

Comment: Post the error details!

Comment: @LUI just retain your array after process is finished.

Comment: Is `claimReports` also a property? Paste the code where you initialise that property.

Comment: NSArray *array; should alloc before storing value and NSMutableArray * claimReports no need to alloc memory just give the reference of array memory   ;

Comment: that wont compile even ;)

Answer (score 2):

Long-story-short, you are treating an instance of `LSClaimReport` as if it was an  `NSMutableArray` instance.

The end.

**EDIT** OK, flippany aside, you are confused about instance variable and local variables and have confused the types of one of your instance variables.

In  `ViewDidLoad` (case incorrect, so if that's copied verbatim then it won't even be called), you reference a local version of `claimReports` which is created and then thrown away:

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *claimReports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [claimReports addObjectsFromArray:[[LADataModelController getSingleton] getClaimReportsOrderedByIncidentDate] ];
}
```

and later you refer to the instance variable version:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return claimReports.count; //crashes here
}
```

Which is clearly a `LSClaimReport` instance and not a `NSMutableArray`.

So it looks like:

1. You have declared the wrong type in your `@interface`.
2. You are not initializing it correctly (you already fixed that bit).

Comment: A flippant answer, to be sure, but who knows what's going on in that code (and who wants to)?

Comment: @trojanfoe i just tried to reduce the code. its all okay now in new edit. can you share any idea if u have on this issue.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the local Arraydeclaration:

```
NSMutableArray * claimReports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

instead use:

```
claimReports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In case this is no Class variable yet, add it to your @interface-declaration:

```
@interface LAMasterViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray * claimReports
}
@end

@implementation LAMasterViewController
```

Comment: This is wrong, please see `trojanfoe`s answer as that is completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your .h file

```
   NSMutableArray * claimReports;
```

and in your .m

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad{
              claimReports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             [claimReports addObjectsFromArray:[[LADataModelController getSingleton] getClaimReportsOrderedByIncidentDate] ];
              }
```

Comment: Why??? What makes the difference between the ivar being private over it being public???

Answer (score 0):

You have few things wrong with your code which cleaning them up will help resolve the issue, the main issue `'-[LSClaimReport count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa54afc0'` is because you are calling `count` on an instance of `LSClaimReport` which clearly shouldn't be happening. Your code seems to think that `claimReports` is an instance of `LSClaimReport` and not an instance of `NSMutableArray`.

As for your code may I recommend changing to (Please see comments in code marked issue)

```
@interface LAMasterViewController ()

// Clearly you want this as a private property so why would you want to change 
// to having this in the .h file which would make it public
// But Issue 1 is here you are missing the semi-colon (`;`) of the end.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *claimReports;

@end

// Issue two you are missing the `@implementation LAMasterViewController`
@implementation LAMasterViewController

// The synthesize is done automatically so getters/setters/ivar are created automatically

// Issue 3: ViewDidLoad isn't a valid selector so ViewDidLoad will never be called
// It is viewDidLoad
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // Issue 4: you missed the call to super
    claimReports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [claimReports addObjectsFromArray:[[LADataModelController getSingleton] getClaimReportsOrderedByIncidentDate]];

}

-(NSArray *)getClaimReportsOrderedByIncidentDate
{ // it returns one record
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ClaimReport" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByIncidentDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateOfIncident" ascending:NO];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortByIncidentDate]];

    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Array Count %i" ,array.count);
    return  array;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return claimReports.count;

}

@end
```